# What does the word "analysis" mean when we say real/mathematical analysis or analytic geometry?

Tags: analysis, soft-question

The choice of the word "analysis" has always confounded me. Is it because we're literally *analyzing* mathematical objects/relationships till we have a clear understanding of things?

Is it quite literally "to analyze" that we have this word or is there more to it than meets the eye?

I can "grossly simplify" *analysis* into saying "algebraic/arithmetic POV" devoid of geometry. However, why was the word "analysis" chosen and when did it first become formally attached to the various fields?

Comment: It feel it's more akin to formalization of the topic at hand, in my experience. For example, calculus and real analysis cover basically the same material in the typical college course - yet the latter is far more rigorous. Personally, though, mathematicians often make very poor poets; the choice of terminology often also conflicts across fields of study, or can be unintuitive. Hell, there's a context in which "analysis" is used as a term for functions (see analytic functions). Granted, this is strictly anecdotal and simply comes from my experience, I don't actually know why this term is used.

Comment: For me the word "analysis" signifies "not algebra". An exception to this is analytic geometry because here one precisely uses algebra to study geometry.